# R: using FOR-loop and IF-ELSE constructs to omit odd numbers in column

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

For a project, I was asked to create a FOR-loop with IF-ELSE construct where I omit the odd numbers in a column of the dataframe.  However, when I was trying to construct it I couldn't get the right answer.  This is how my code looks:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_columns)) {
  if (my_columns$id[[i]] %% 2 != 0) {
    my_columns$id <- my_columns$id[[-i]]
  }
}
```

Then R returns this error message:

```
 Error in my_columns$id[[-i]] : 
 attempt to select more than one element in integerOneIndex
```

I think I am making a mistake in the part where the if statement has to return a value.  Could you please tell me what my mistake is?  Moreover, can you help me create the for-loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Check your indexing at my_columns$id[[-i]]. If you iterate over a list you can assign integer numbers from 1 to n, but you are assigning a negative -1. Give me please further info and some reproducible example/data

Comment: You've have to omit the odd numbers aka supply a missing value. In R missing values ars `NA`. So there's your clue.

Comment: Hi! I've used infominer's clue and produced this which returns my needed values:

for(i in 1:nrow(my_columns)) {
  if (my_columns$id[[i]] %% 2 != 0) {
   my_columns$id[[i]] <- NA
  }
}

my_columns <- na.omit(my_columns)

Is there any more efficient way to do the same task?

Comment: R is a vector language there is no need for a loop.  `my_columns[my_columns$id %% 2==0, ]` will return the even rows significantly faster than using the loop.